# cant execute zip item for 2nd time

Tags: python, zip

```
index_both    = zip(index_start, index_end)

_             = [ws.merge_cells(f'A{start}:A{end}') for start, end in index_both]  # merge from A1 to A4314
_             = [ws.merge_cells(f'B{start}:B{end}') for start, end in index_both]  # merge from B1 to B4314
```

just cant execute the final code.
Here have three action:

1. zip and assign this to `index_both`
2. process `index_both` in a list comprehension
3. process it again in another list comprehension

so # 3 doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I just figure out my problem.

because I use

```
index_both    = zip(index_start, index_end)
```

and that generates a series of numbers just one time. And doesn't generate it again for 2nd time.

instead, I should use:

```
index_both    = list(zip(index_start, index_end))
```

this will keep in memory, so I can re-use the numbers.